# Is it possible to destroy AT mines with small arms fire?

Tags: battlefield-3

In BC2 it was possible to destroy AT mines with rifle fire. I've tried few times in BF3 and it just doesn't seem to work. Is it possible at all?

So far I've been only successful at destroying mines with heavy weapons or explosives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not. Without an explosive weapon you can't destroy AT mines.

If you're an Engineer though, you can run over to them and hold reload to pick them up (this won't increase your ammo if you're using AT mines though).

Comment: I'll add one correction, the only small arms fire that will blow up AT mines is frag rounds from the various shotguns

Answer (score 2):

Sniper rifles and grenades can be used to detonate and destroy AT mines -- at least, I have used them to.

However pistols, rifles, etc do not work to blow up mines, no matter how much you fire.

Comment: Hmm, do all sniper rifles work? I'm going to have to do some testing, I did not know this.